# How to increase order id from particular number in magento

Tags: magento

In magento, 
How to increase order id from particular number?
For Ex. current order id is 10000031 . I want next order id from 5001.
Next order ids should go like 5001,5002,5003 ......etc.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you have to modify your database as well as some core code.

**Change in database tables:**

1. **Change table 'eav_entity_type':**

   ```
     check row where entity_type_code=order,
     set increment_pad_length=1
   ```

**Query:**

```
update eav_entity_type set increment_pad_length = '1' where entity_type_id = 5;
```

1. **Change table eav_entity_store:**

   check row where entity_type_id = 5;

   set increment_last_id = '5000'

**Query:**

```
update eav_entity_store set increment_last_id = '5000' where entity_type_id = 5;
```

**Change in code:**

Go to app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Increment/Abstract.php

(a)  See the code:

```
public function getPadLength()
{
    $padLength = $this->getData('pad_length');
    if (empty($padLength)) {
       $padLength = 0; 
    }
    return $padLength;
}
```

Here change

```
$padLength = 0;
```

(b)   See the code:

```
public function format($id)
{
   // $result = $this->getPrefix();
    $result.= str_pad((string)$id, $this->getPadLength(), $this->getPadChar(), STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment the line:

```
//$result = $this->getPrefix();
```

You are done.Let me know if you have any problem regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

check below url

http://ashsmith.co/2012/12/quick-tip-change-magento-default-increment-id-for-orders-invoices/

hope this help you